# Get the name of the application with window title "someWinTitle"

Tags: applescript

What is the simplest way to get the name of the application that has a window with title "someWinTitle".

I know that it can be found by cycling through all the applications in loops but is there an elegant one liner to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filters in AppleScript to get a list of filtered objects, if the application supports it of course. Here's an example that will return the process(es) whose browsers has this page open.

```
tell application "System Events"
    get name of every process whose name of every window contains "applescript - Get the name of the application with window title \"someWinTitle\" - Stack Overflow"
end tell
```